# PHP - Printing RAW not printed (Thermal Printer)

Tags: php, printing, zebra-printers

I already create PHP function using ext printer.dll and its work when print TEXT only.

This my PHP function

```
$handle = printer_open('Printer Name'); 
        printer_start_doc($handle, 'My Document200');
        printer_start_page($handle);
        $ret = printer_write($handle,'Hello');
        printer_end_page($handle);
        printer_end_doc($handle);
        printer_close($handle);
```

it works .

But when iam print RAW script it returned blank (but printer is running)
This is my PHP function for RAW (using ZPL command)

```
            $handle = printer_open('Printer Name'); //or it could be \\pcname\printername
        printer_start_doc($handle, 'My Document200');
        printer_start_page($handle);
        printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, 'RAW');

        $esc = chr(94);
        $data = ' ';
        $data .= $esc . 'XA';
        $data .= $esc . 'FX  Third section with barcod' ;
        $data .= $esc . 'BY1,5,30' ;
        $data .= $esc . 'FO600,130' . $esc . 'BC' . $esc . 'FD1234' . $esc . 'FS';
        $data .= $esc . 'XZ';

        $ret = printer_write($handle,$data);
        //close the printer handle
        printer_end_page($handle);
        printer_end_doc($handle);
        printer_close($handle);
```

I am using Wincode C342 Printer which is support ZPL command. What is wrong? is it because driver?

Comment: Did you try the lowercase: `printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw");`

Comment: yes but no luck